# Tate Cohomology of Squares

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory, group-cohomology, local-field, galois-cohomology

Let $L | \mathbb{Q}_p$ be a finite Galois extension with Galois group $G$. What is known about the group $H^{-1} (G, L^\times / (L^\times)^p)$?

I'm particularly interested in the case of a non-abelian wildly ramified extensions $L | \mathbb{Q}_p$. Even more precisely, I need to show that $H^{-1} (A_4, L^\times / (L^\times)^2) = 0$, where $L | \mathbb{Q}_2$ denotes the unique extension having Galois group $A_4$. (I am confident this statement holds due to computations using MAGMA.)

This is how far I've come yet: There is an element $x \in L^\times$ such that $N_{L | K} (x) = - 1$ and the statement above is, since $H^{-1}( A_4, L^\times) \cong \mathbb{Z} / 2 \mathbb{Z}$, equivalent to saying that $x^2 \neq 0$ in $H^{-1} (A_4, L^\times)$. Using the exact sequence
$$ 1 \to H^{-1} (A_4, L^\times) \stackrel{\cdot 2}{\to} H^{-1}(A_4, (L^\times)^2) \to \{ \pm 1\} \to 1 $$
obtained from the long exact sequence induced by $L^\times \stackrel{\cdot 2}{\to} (L^\times)^2$ this is equvialent to $H^{-1} (A_4, (L^\times)^2)$ being cyclic.

However, I do not know how to proceed from here as I feel I've literally squeezed out every information one could get from related long exact sequences in cohomology. Can you suggest what else I could try or where I could look for getting inspiration?

Comment: Why are you interested specifically in $H^{-1}$ ?

Comment: Well, I am actually looking for all quadratic extensions $L'$ of $L$ such that the Galois group $G_{L' | L}$ is contained in the centre of $G_{L' | \mathbb{Q}_2}$, i. e. central extensions. These correspond to subgroups of the co-invariants $(L^\times / (L^\times)^2 )_{A_4}$ by local class field theory and the only obstruction in computing the co-invariants is my lack of knowledge about H^{-1} (A_4,  (L^\times / (L^\times)^2)$.

Comment: But, with your notations, if you find a quadratic extension L'/L such that L' is Galois over $Q_p$, automatically it will be central, because G(L'/$Q_p$) will stabilize G(L'/L), which will be central because it's just $\pm 1$. If you follow this path, you can characterize the candidates L' using Kummer theory. I can give the details if you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think that Tate cohomology is useful here, at least because we don't control a priori $H^{-1} (G, L^*)$, whereas $H^1 (G, L^*)=0$ by Hilbert's $90$. Let us first fix the general setting: $L/K$ is a finite Galois extension of fields of characteristic $\neq 2$, and you want to classify the quadratic extensions $L'/L$ s.t. $L'/K$ is Galois. NB: this is the problem exposed in your comment. The calculation of $H^{-1}(G,L^*/{L^*}^2)$ could also be carried on following the method explained below, but I don't see the motivation.

Since $L$ contains $W_2:=(\pm 1)$, every quadratic extension $L'/L$ is of the form $L'=L(\sqrt a)$, $a\in L^*, a\notin {L^*}^2$; actually, $L'$ depends only on the class $\bar a\in X_L:=L^*/{L^*}^2$. An easy classical argument shows that $L'/K$ is Galois iff $a/s(a)\in {L^*}^2$ for all $s\in G$; in other words our extensions $L'$ are classified by the group of invariants ${X_L}^G$, and our task is the description of ${X_L}^G$ in cohomological terms. This will be done by studying the $G$-cohomology of the two tautological exact sequences $1\to {L^*}^2\to L^* \to X_L\to 1$ and $1\to W_2\to  L^*\to {L^*}^2\to 1$.

The first exact sequence gives $...\to X_K \to {X_L}^G \to H^1(G, {L^*}^2) \to H^1(G, L^*)=0$. Besides, denoting by $\epsilon$ the natural map $X_K \to {X_L}^G$, it is obvious  that Ker $\epsilon =(K^* \cap {L^*}^2)/{K^*}^2$, which  is no other than Hom $(G, W_2)$ by Kummer theory. Summarizing, we have an exact sequence  **(1)** $0\to X_K $/Hom $(G, W_2)$ $\to {X_L}^G \to H^1(G, {L^*}^2)\to 0$ , and it remains to describe $H^1(G, {L^*}^2)$.

The second exact sequence gives **(2)** $0\to H^1(G, {L^*}^2) \to H^2(G, W_2)\to H^2(G, L^*)\to ...$ Here the $G$-action on $W_2$ is trivial, hence $H^2(G, W_2)$ depends only on the structure of $G$, and given $G$, it can be dismantled using general cohomological tools. Try for example $G=A_4$. As for the relative Brauer group $H^2(G, L^*)$  attached to the extension $L/K$ , it depends on the field $K$. If for instance $K=\mathbf Q_p$ (or more generally a $p$-adic local field), local CFT tells us that $H^2(G, L^*)$ is cyclic of order $[L:K]$; since $H^2(G, W_2)$ is killed by $2$, its image will be $0$ or $\mathbf Z/2$, the distinction between the two cases depending on normic computations.

NB : the above study carries on word for word when replacing $2$ by any prime $p$, under the hypothesis that $K$ has characteristic $\neq p$ and contains the group $W_p$ of $p$-th roots of $1$.

**Complement**. You added a question whether *all* the Galois extensions $L'/\mathbf Q_2$ thus obtained are split. This can be answered by manipulating inflation-restriction, as I said, to reduce to more amenable quotients of $G$. Let us fix some notations : $k=\mathbf Q_2$ for simplicity, $G=Gal(L/k)=$ $A_4, H=C_2 \times C_2 =$ the $2$-Sylow subgroup of $A_4, F=$ the fixed field of $H, G^{ab}=G/H=C_3$. It is classically known that $H^2(G, W_2)=C_2$ and $H^2(H, W_2)=C_2 \times C_2$ .

Let us first rewrite the exact sequence **(2)** as **(3)**  $0\to H^1(G, {L^*}^2) \to H^2(G, W_2)\to C\to 0$, where $C=C_2$ or $(1)$ denotes the image of $H^2(G, W_2)$ in the relative Brauer group $H^2(G, L^*)$. Replacing $k$ and $G$ by $F$ and $H$, we obtain a similar exact sequence **(4)** $0\to H^1(H, {L^*}^2) \to H^2(H, W_2)\to C'  \to 0$, with $C'=C_2$ or $(1)$, and the restriction map yields a commutative diagram with exact lines **(3)** and **(4)** and vertical connecting maps denoted $res_1 , res_2 , res_3$ [unfortunately I don't know how to type commutative diagrams].

1) By local CFT, the rightmost $res_3$ between the two relative Brauer groups is just multiplication by $3=[F:k]$, hence an isomorphism. Consider $res_1$, which takes place in the inf-res exact sequence $0\to H^1 (G^{ab},F^* \cap {L^*}^2)\to H^1(G,{L^*}^2)\to {H^1(H,{L^*}^2)}^G \to H^2 (G^{ab},F^* \cap {L^*}^2)$. Since $G^{ab}$ is cyclic, the $G^{ab}$-cohomology of the exact sequence $1\to {F^*}^2 \to F^* \cap {L^*}^2 \to (F^* \cap {L^*}^2)/ {F^*}^2 \to 1$ reads ${\hat H}^0((F^* \cap {L^*}^2)/ {F^*}^2)\to H^1({F^*}^2)\to {H^1(F^*\cap {L^*}^2)}^G \to H^1((F^* \cap {L^*}^2)/ {F^*}^2)$ (we omitted to write $G^{ab}$). Because $2$ and $3$ are coprime, the first and last term vanish to give an isomorphism $H^1({F^*}^2)\cong {H^1(F^*\cap {L^*}^2)}^G$. But we have seen above that $H^1({F^*}^2)$ describes the quadratic extensions $M/F$ which are Galois over $k$, and these are necessarily split because $2$ and $3$ are coprime. Hence $res_1$ is injective, and consequently so is $res_2$. Applying the snake lemma to the commutative diagram we get an exact sequence $0\to$ Coker $res_1 \to C_2 \to$ Coker $res_3\to 0$ . Denote by $c,c'$ the orders of $C, C'$, and by $h^1(G), h^1(H)$ the orders of $H^1(G, {L^*}^2),H^1(H, {L^*}^2)$. A simple diagram chase gives $h^1(H)/h^1(G)=2c/c'$ .

2) It remains to compute $H^1(H, {L^*}^2)$, or rather its image in $H^2(H, W_2)$, which classifies the quadratic extensions $L''/L$ which are Galois over $F$. Their Galois groups, described by the classes of $H^2(H, W_2)$, are of three different types : $C_2 \times C_2, D_8$ (dihedral) or $H_8$ (quaternionic). The first type is split abelian, so we need to study only the two non abelian types using techniques of the embedding problem. Let $L=F(\sqrt \alpha, \sqrt \beta)$. It is easy to show that $L/F$ can be embedded into a $D_8$-extension, cyclic over $F(\sqrt \alpha\beta)$ iff $\alpha$ is a norm from $F(\sqrt \beta)$. In our case here, this normic condition can be expressed in terms of the local Hilbert symbol $<.,.>$ attached to $F$; it simply reads $<\alpha, \beta>=0$ (in additive notation). The embeddability into an $H_8$-extension is more complicated; a necessary and sufficient condition reads $<\alpha,-1>+<\beta,-1>+<\alpha, \beta>=0$ (Fröhlich, (1985)). To conclude we need to know an explicit description of $L/F$, hence my previous question about how you got yo $A_4$-extension of $\mathbf Q_2$. But I forgot about the Fröhlich condition ! The prime $2$ is always a mess.

Comment: Thank you! After the helpful hint you gave in your comment above I also came to those conclusions you just explained, sorry for not having responded earlier! Actually, I want to show there are exactly seven such fields $L'$ which would be equivalent to $H^1 (G, (L^\times)^2)$ vanishing. Do you think those "normic computations" you mentioned would lead to such a vanishing statment? May I ask how they would look like?

Comment: Surely you don't expect a general solution for a general G. What I had in mind was a favourable cse (i.e. when G is solvable) when you can manipulate a spectral sequence (e.g. inflation-restriction) to reduce to a more amenable quotient of G, and so on, and ultimately to a cyclic group for which ${\hat H}^0 = H^2$. For example G=$A_4$  admits a normal subgroup $C_2 \times C_2$, with corresponding quotient $C_3$.

Comment: NB. In the latter case you expect $H^1(G, {L^*}^2) =0$, or equivalently that the image of $X_K$ under $\epsilon$ is ${X_L} ^G$. But this means that the extension of Galois groups splits (i.e. is a semi-direct product), or equivalently every L' is obtained  by adding to L a square root of an element of ${Q^*}_2$. How do you arrive at the total number of  seven ? Is it because ${Q^*}_2$ modulo squares is $\cong C_2 \times C_2 \times C_2$ and $A_4$ admits no subgroup of index 2 ?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I expect that every such $L'$ in my, admittedly very special, case is of the form $L \cdot K$, where $K | \mathbb{Q}_2$ is quadratic. Every such composite $L \cdot K$ is uniquely determined by $K$, so it suffices to count the quadratic extensions of $\mathbb{Q}_2$.

Comment: You added a question whether *all* the Galois extensions $L'/\mathbf Q_2$ thus obtained are split. This can be answered by manipulating inflation-restriction, as I said, to reduce to more amenable quotients of $G$. I added a complement to my first answer.

Comment: Thanks for the added complement! A quick question: Why can't $C_4 \times C_2$ apperar as a Galois group of $L'' | F$? Maybe it is better to look at $res_2$ instead, because we know that it is injective and also know the isomorphism types of the two groups it connects. (By the way, do you happen to know a reference for these classical results on $H^2 (G, W_2)$ and $H^2 (H, W_2)$, respectively?)

Comment: Regarding your question on the existence of $L$: I examined the quotient $X_F = F^\times / (F^\times)^2$ and found exactly one subgroup $U$ of  index 4 such that the Galois group $G_{F | \mathbb{Q}_2}$ acts non-trivially on $X_F / U$. Now local class field theory gives us a field $L$ such that $L | \mathbb{Q}_2$ is a non-abelian Galois extension and $G_{L | \mathbb{Q}_2} = A_4$ for group-theoretic reasons.

Comment: If you appeal to group-theory, you might as well use the following  result over any field of characteristic $\neq 2$: let $f\in k[X]$ be a separable irreducible quartic, $L=k(x_i), i=1,...,4$ its splitting field, $G=Gal(L/k)$. Because of the known structure of the 2-Sylow subgroup of $A_4$, introduce $a=x_1x_2+x_3x_4, b=x_1x_3+x_2x_4, c=x_1x_4+x_2x_3$. The polynomial  $g=(X-a)(X-b)(X-c)$ is called the * resolvent cubic* of $f$. Let $m$ be the degree over $k$ of the splitting field of $g$. Then $G=A_4$ iff $m=3$. The other values $1\le m\le 6$ characterize all the possible types of $G$.

Comment: Sorry for asking again, but there are two arguments in your proof that are still unclear to me. The map $res_3$ is a restriction of $C_{12} \cong H^2( G, L^\times) \stackrel{\cdot 3}{\longrightarrow} H^2 (H, L^\times) \cong C_4$, so the domain of $res_3$ does not meet the kernel and $res_3$ is thus injective. Is it easy to see that $res_3$ is also surjective? Could you also give more details on why $D_8$ and $H_8$ can't appear both as a Galois group of some extension $L'' | F$?

Comment: 1) In the commutative diagram, C is not the relative Brauer group , it's the image of $H^2(., W_2)$. But the Brauer group is cyclic, and $H^2(., W_2)$ is killed by 2, so C is cyclic of order at most 2   2) The answer to your 2nd question is already in the last § of my answer, I added an explanation yesterday

Comment: (1) Why can't it happen that the image of $H^2 (G, W_2)$ is trivial whereas the image of $H^2 (H, W_2)$ is of order 2? (2) Quite frankly, I don't get the "\Leftarrow" part of the iff-statement in your added explanation and why this does the job.

Comment: I tried to edit my post, but got a problem of (weirdly sluggish) typo. I'll try again later.

Comment: I finished editing, but the typo problems remain (due to length ?)

Comment: I think, I am able to complete the proof by explicit computations. I will try that and, if it works, write it here afterwards.

Comment: I'd be glad if it works. Good luck !

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Nguyen Quang Do's excellent and comprehensive answer I want to show how one can answer my complementary question on whether all quadratic extensions $L' | L$ such that $L' | \mathbb{Q}_2$ is Galois define in fact a split Galois extension $L' | \mathbb{Q}_2$. (This is equivalent to the question on the vanishing of $H^{-1} (A_4, L^\times / (L^\times)^2)$ raised in my original post.)

Observe that any such quadratic extension $L' | L$ yielding a Galois extension $L' | \mathbb{Q}_2$ is in fact a central extension of $L | \mathbb{Q}_2$, hence the Galois group of $L' | \mathbb{Q}_2$ is $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \times A_4$ or $SL_2 (\mathbb{F}_3)$ (these are the only central extensions of $A_4$). Suppose $G_{L ' | \mathbb{Q}_2} = SL_2 (\mathbb{F}_3)$, then $L' | F$, where $F | \mathbb{Q}_2$ is the unique subextension of $L | \mathbb{Q}_2$ of degree 3, is a Galois extension with Galois group $Q$ (the quaternion group). It therefore suffices to show that $L | F$ can not be embedded into a extension with Galois group $Q$. To do so, we will be using Fröhlich's Condition, which asserts that this is the case if and only if
$$ \langle a, b \rangle \cdot \langle a, - 1\rangle \cdot \langle b, - 1 \rangle = - 1, \qquad  \quad (\ast)$$
where $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ denotes the Hilbert symbol and $L = F(\sqrt{a}, \sqrt{b})$ (see (7.7) in Fröhlich, A.: *Orthogonal representations of Galois groups, Stiefel-Whitney classes and Hasse-Witt invariants*, 1985).

We will therefore now first determine $a$ and $b$.

It is easy to see that $F| \mathbb{Q}_2$ is unramified, hence $F = \mathbb{Q}_2 (\alpha)$, where $\alpha \in F^\times$ is a root of $X^3  + X + 1$. Denote by $\varphi$ the Frobenius of $F | \mathbb{Q}_2$. One now checks that $\{2, -1, 1 + 2\alpha,  1 + 2 \varphi (\alpha), 5\}$ is an $\mathbb{F}_2$-basis of $F^\times / (F^\times)^2)$ and that
$$ N_{F | \mathbb{Q}_2} (1 + 2\alpha) = N_{F | \mathbb{Q}_2} ( 1 + 2 \varphi(\alpha)) = - 3 \equiv 5 \mod (F^\times)^2. $$
The action of $G_{F | \mathbb{Q}_2}$ on $F^\times / (F^\times)^2$ is therefore given by 
$$ \varphi (1 + 2 \alpha) = 1 + 2 \varphi (\alpha), \qquad \varphi (1 + 2 \varphi (\alpha)) = 5 (1 + 2 \alpha)(1 + 2 \varphi (\alpha)) $$
and fixing all other basis vectors. By writing down explicitely all orbits of this action one sees that the only $G_{F | \mathbb{Q}_2}$-stable subgroup of order 4 of $F^\times / (F^\times)^2$ on which $G_{F | \mathbb{Q}_2}$ acts non-trivially is 
$$\{ 1, 5(1 + 2 \alpha), 5(1 + 2 \varphi(\alpha)), (1 + 2 \alpha)(1 + 2 \varphi(\alpha)) \}.$$
Hence $L = F \left (\sqrt{5(1 + 2 \alpha)}, \sqrt{5(1 + 2 \varphi(\alpha)})\right)$ by Kummer Theory. A similar discussion (looking for stable subgroups $U$ with non-trivial action on the quotient of $F^\times / (F^\times)^2$ by $U$) gives that the norm group of $L | F$ is 
$$ N_{L | F} (L^\times) = \langle 2 \rangle \times \mu_7 \times \langle -1, U^{(2)}_F \rangle, $$
where $\mu_7 \subseteq F^\times$ denotes the $7$-th roots of unity. One can now, using $\langle a, -1 \rangle = \langle -1, a\rangle^{-1}$, check that $(\ast)$ holds.